# Removing days from timedelta index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df1` with index:

```
0 days 11:45:39
0 days 11:45:39
0 days 12:45:39
```

However, I am trying to remove the days portion of this. Is there a way to do this?
The dtype of index currently is timedelta

Comment: whats the reason for removing it? for cosmetic purposes ?

Comment: I'm trying to plot a graph without the days, so in a sense yes.

Comment: whats the current dtype of the column is it a proper timedelta? and what if you have values greater than 1 day

Comment: Hi, edited original post.

Comment: @Nic, you can use [`dt.hour`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html) to get the diff in hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always the option of formatting it as a string, if all you want to do is use it for plotting labels:

```
# if the index is a string,
# df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df.index, errors='coerce')
(pd.to_datetime('2020') + df.index).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
# Index(['11:45:39', '11:45:39', '12:45:39'], dtype='object', name='delta')
```

---

Another option using the power of list comprehensions:

```
[str(dt) for dt in  df.index.to_pytimedelta()]
# ['11:45:39', '11:45:39', '12:45:39']
```